# Проблема Ajax на мобильных (андроид)

Tags: ajax

Отправка формы с сайта реализована при помощи ajax. И с десктопов и с планшетов все отправляется. Только вот success работает только на декстопах. Почему так?

```
$("#form-popup").submit(function() {
  //Change 
  var thp = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mail.php',
    data: thp.serialize(),
    success: function() {
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: "#thanksModal",
          type: 'inline'
        }
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        // Done Functions 
        thp.trigger("reset");
        $.magnificPopup.close();
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: потому что, если Вы считаете Ваши две строчки достаточно полной формулировкой вопроса, на который кто-то может дать осмысленный ответ, представляю себе, как написан код

Comment: Не ругайтесь. Первый раз пользуюсь сервисом!

Comment: Хорошо, тогда уже заодно не буду придираться к слову "сервис" :). Может это просто `magnificPopup` не работает на планшетах, а не `success`?

Comment: Не думаю, Пытались заменить код с магнификом на обычный алерт так же не сработало. Думаю дело все таки в саксесе.

Comment: добавьте обработчик `error` в параметр `$.ajax` и посмотрите, вызывается ли он

Comment: пробывали. не реагирует

Comment: ошибки в консоли браузера? (пробовали)

Comment: может быть обработчик `submit` не вызывается? вставьте `alert` в его начало.

Comment: На компе все ок. Именно на планшетах и смартфонах сообщения уходят, но при этом не работает все то что находится в success. А как посмотреть в консоле на андроиде.........

Comment: Решено. Помогло, что данный код из файла JS переместили под саму форму.